# password mismatch alert javascript on onkeypress

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I want to check whether confirm password matches with password or not, through onkeypress() function. It's not working.. Some of the part working like password length must be 6 character. But, I'm having problem.. when i'm typing value for confirm password.. it is showing div error message even after when it matches with the password value which i entered in password text. Please help. Here is my code.

```
<input type='password' class='Register-textbox Password' name="Password" onkeypress="RegistrationValidation()">

<input type='password' class='Register-textbox ConfirmPassword' name="ConfirmPassword"  onkeypress="RegistrationValidation()">

<div class="ShowPasswordNotMatchesError" style="display:none;">
  * Password Mismatch
</div>

<script>
function RegistrationValidation()
{
       var PasswordVal=$('.Password').val();
       var ConfirmPasswordVal=$('.ConfirmPassword').val();
       if(PasswordVal!=ConfirmPasswordVal)
       {
        $('.ShowPasswordNotMatchesError').show();
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using jQuery, please make use of those functions. I have made the following changes:

1. Made the code unobtrusive.
2. Checked for the correctness on `blur()`.
3. Checked only if the user has entered something.
4. Removed unnecessary braces.
5. Added reverse condition.

Try this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".Register-textbox").blur(function () {
    var PasswordVal=$('.Password').val();
    var ConfirmPasswordVal=$('.ConfirmPassword').val();
    if(PasswordVal != ConfirmPasswordVal && ConfirmPasswordVal.length > 0 && PasswordVal.length > 0)
      $('.ShowPasswordNotMatchesError').show();
    else
      $('.ShowPasswordNotMatchesError').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='password' class='Register-textbox Password' name="Password" />
<input type='password' class='Register-textbox ConfirmPassword' name="ConfirmPassword" />
<div class="ShowPasswordNotMatchesError" style="display:none;">
  * Password Mismatch
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Praveen. There will be no onkeypress() function then on textfield?

Comment: You can use the same function or event by changing the `blur` to `keyup`. Would you like to try and tell me if it works @DanishEnam?

Comment: But, one more additional thing i will ask.. how can i stop him submitting the form.. when password and confirm password not matches

Comment: @DanishEnam In the `<form>` tag, specify an `onsubmit` that uses a similar check and returns a boolean. Returning `false` will prevent the form from submitting.